# Once a method is implemented in a computer program, then does learning the theory become less useful use of time?

Tags: finite-element, fluid-dynamics, education

Once a method is implemented in a computer program, then does learning the theory become less useful use of time?

This has confused me. I used to view that all things should be studied from first principles, but lately I've thought that this might well be uneconomical.

For example, consider FreeFEM or something. Once it's usable there, then how much theory does one really need to study as an end-user?

But is there some way to gauge what one should do?

My idea was to start with the software and consult theory when needed.

Rather than learn theory before learning applications (the common way in academia).

If the same applies as with APIs in general, then the end-user need not know full implementational details.

Comment: Opinion-based maybe, but can we make this evidence-based?

Comment: The Community here is focused on using software/programming to solve or investigate scientific/technical problems.  I don't see how thinking about "a method [which] is implemented in a computer program" in broad terms will admit analysis of whether theory should be studied before or "when needed".  Some theory is typically needed to specify what the program is supposed to do, and to provide tests to make sure the results are correct.  Perhaps you can drill down on the example of FreeFEm, with details of where you progressed in studies of numerical PDEs.

Comment: @hardmath I think this question is important, because it's like asking, how much RTM to do with numerical software packages. When it comes to Matlab or something, people can often do quite a bit of things with having just an "input/output" sense of what the thing does. So with a FEM module, does an user really need to think about convergence or something?

Comment: Why study the 4 operations when you have calculators? Why learn algebra when there's Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: I've observed that many users of FEM have little clue about stability or convergence or error estimates. Most of the time they do just fine.

Comment: @knl Exactly. I think a lot of engineers treat the numerical aspect of the software just as a thing to check that it passes without errors. Rather than, whether the properties have some sort of physical meaning.

Comment: Are FEM codes so much different from, say, image processing algorithms? If you hit the "deblur" button, do you need to know what happens internally?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I am asking what level a computational scientist might be at, w.r.t. to already implemented software.

Comment: Who cares? Learn the theory or don't learn the theory. What do you do with all the time that you saved not learning theory ? Chess is only properly played by computers but there are still humans learning it.